# cant figure out how jquerymobile.com makes their section headers

Tags: html, css

[jquerymoble.com](http://jquerymobile.com/) has section headers that look like they wrap around the edge of the page.
This wrapping effect is achieved by having a little triangle above the div containing the text. i **cannot for the life of my figure out what css creates this triangle**.

If you have firebug, go the [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/) and replace (in html edit mode) the entire body tag with this html:

```
<header id="header">      
   <section id="page">
  <p class="flag"><em><a style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" href="http://jquerymobile.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-alpha-2-released/">jQuery Mobile 1.0 Alpha 2 Released!</a></em></p>
  </section>
</header>
```

how do they get that wrapping effect on the left?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their CSS:

```
#page .flag:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  border-color: transparent #FFC32C #FFC32C transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg,0deg) translate(-1px,0);
  transform: skew(10deg,0deg);
}
```

It looks as if they are using the [CSS border method](http://tantek.com/CSS/Examples/polygons.html) to create the shape.